# Postmaster Functions

Tags: postmaster

**I want to purchase this add-on but not sure if it will fit into what I need.  Maybe someone who already has it can let me know?**

1) Can the add-on be setup to email a registered user when that end user submits a new entry (confirming they submitted an entry)?  Plus email the admin.

2) Does this email the end user to new updates to their entries?  Does Postmaster send an email to the end-user if the admin updates their entry via the ACP or the front end using Channel:Form?

3) A bit of a stretch, but does the add-on have the ability to update a channel entry from an email?

4) Can the add-on notify on a per user basis if I create (as admin) a new entry that I only want them to be contacted on (assign them to get a notification)?  I assign it to the member and they get an email saying they have a new entry waiting for them.

Any clarification is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Can the add-on be setup to email a registered user when that end user submits a new entry (confirming they submitted an entry)? Plus email the admin.

Yes, if you setup a parcel to do this.

> 2) Does this email the end user to new updates to their entries? Does Postmaster send an email to the end-user if the admin updates their entry via the ACP or the front end using Channel:Form?

Yes, if you setup a parcel to do this.

> 3) A bit of a stretch, but does the add-on have the ability to update a channel entry from an email?

No, it does not.

> 4) Can the add-on notify on a per user basis if I create (as admin) a new entry that I only want them to be contacted on (assign them to get a notification)? I assign it to the member and they get an email saying they have a new entry waiting for them.

I don't think so - the conditions under which an email parcel gets sent have Member Group criteria, but not per-member criteria.

Comment: As Derek said, allowing Channel posts via email (which will ead to database population is thraught with issues around security and injection attacks too, I'd forget this idea!

Comment: Thanks Derek! I guess the only way I will fully know is if I get the module but it's close, as long as it will use per member on their own entries, but #4 has me a little concerned, if it's on per Member Group and not per member, hmmmm.

With the send through email, I would only need this once the channel entry is started, and then match up the subject and email to be able to insert into the db.

Comment: Derek do you currently use Postmaster?

Comment: I've used it on a few projects for entry notifications, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to throw another alternative into the hat...

[MX Notify Control](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control)

This module is free so you'll not spend any £££ trying it out, and I do beleive it will fulfill point 4, as long as you set up the user to notify as the author at least...

Comment: I will check that out, it's been awhile.  I would like a complete module to hot all the point but maybe that is Postmaster, I just don't know and the dev has been mia for 3 weeks now.